# Convert date to string then add to

Tags: vb.net, winforms, date, datagridview

The `cmbTS` and `cmbTA` cant get the *x* and *y* as text

The `datagridview1.item(4,i)` and `datagridview1.item(5,i)` is a date type. I want to be converted into string so that I can put it on my `combobox` as its text. My `combobox` is `cmbTS` and `cmbTA`.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        btnEdit.Visible = True
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim x As String = CStr(DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value.ToString)
        Dim y As String = CStr(DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value.ToString)

        MsgBox(x)
        MsgBox(y)

        txtTrainID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        txtRouteID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        txtLine.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        cmbLine1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        cmbLine2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        cmbLine3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        cmbTS.Text = x
        cmbTA.Text = y
        txtTrainName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
        cmbFlag.Text = DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to a combobox you need to use cmbBox.Items.Add, so it would be

```
cmbTS.items.Add(x)
cmbTA.items.Add(y)
```

If you will only have the one item in the combobox and you want it to show up you need to set the selectedindex property like:

```
cmbTS.SelectedIndex = 0
cmbTA.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Also when declaring X and Y you are converting a string to a string, so you don't really need the CStr there, since you have .tostring at the end.

Edit - since there is only one date, wouldn't a DateTimePicker be a better choice than a ComboBox?